Magento 2.4.5 admin grid never loads
I have installed my Magento development server with a copy of the production server, everything works apart from all admin pages that rely on the grid, which never load.
Upon attempting to load any grid (be that CMS listings, Customers, Products, Search Terms, etc.), I first receive an Attention - Something went wrong message, quickly followed by a second Attention - Something went wrong message. Clicking OK on both of these clears them away, but then the loading icon just spins forever.
Additionally, the grid data is not populated at any point.
I have tried disabling Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Grid Settings > Asynchronous indexing, on the off-chance it would help, but it has had no effect.
Watching both var/log/system.log and var/log/debug.log only shows the following upon page load, but I don't think it's related to my problem after researching this log entry (I could be wrong however):
main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively.
Watching my /var/log/apache2/error.log shows nothing upon page reload either, so I'm at a loss how to fix this issue.
Any help, advice and/or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Update:
After trying Claims suggestion and it having no effect, I will next be looking at replacing the entire vendor folders on the off-chance that previous "designers" mucked around in the core files at some point. I will update further should this not help, or add it as an  answer if it fixes the issue.

Even though the answer given did not help me, it may help other users in the future, so I have marked it as accepted. I no longer have the ability to attempt the "fix" I mentioned in my update, so cannot test whether it would fully resolve my issue.

I'm suggesting you to check your database, first look at your admin id, then go to be ui_bookmark table and check the lines matching your admin user id and the namespace product_listing. Deleting these lines might fix your issue if something wrong was stored there. If not, the issue is deeper that juste a printing of the view.

As this is my development server, after checking the admin id inside ui_bookmark I decided it was just best to empty the entire table (after taking a backup). I then logged into the admin area, cleared the caches, and then tried a grid listing page (specifically CMS Pages) and sadly I receive the same problem. Thank you for your tip though.
